# Django:v1.9 migrate the exiting model ERROR

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am running web application with Django 1.9 and have many models. (It may be too long)

**The old models**:

```
class Application_Delete_History(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    delete_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Review_Manager(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

And I have added many data in 2 models.
And with my stupid action I created 2 new models:

```
class Application_Status_Notification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True,blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    last_use = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True, default=None)

And the worst, I edit the old one:

class Application_Delete_History(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    delete_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # Add:
    is_fa = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_ide = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    applicant = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True) # with out : null=True,
    defect_manager = models.ForeignKey(Review_Manager,null=True, default=None)
    admin_comment = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
```

And run: python3.4 manage.py migrate (i did makemigrations and sqlmigrate)

> ```
>    And the ERROR show up:
>     ForeignKey can't be fill (The data allready exit conflix with it)
>     ~> The models change but Migare FAIL.
> ```

Now i want to fix this problem BUT:
When i delete the new migrations and create a new one 1 got:

## I am sure that i edited

```
 defect_manager = models.ForeignKey(Review_Manager,null=True, default=None)
```

And:

```
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'admin_comment'")
```

This issue DON'T HAPPEN in Django 1.11 (i am test with it and can edit data because: Migrate will rename the exited to model_old and map it to renew one)

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Add field defect_manager to application_delete_history
--
ALTER TABLE "table_application_delete_history" RENAME TO "table_application_dele
te_history__old";
CREATE TABLE "table_application_delete_history" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY K
EY AUTOINCREMENT, "defect_manager_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "table_review_mana
ger" ("id"), "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL, "delete_time" datetime NULL, "status"
 bool NOT NULL, "admin_comment" varchar(256) NULL, "applicant" varchar(64) NULL,
 "is_fa" bool NULL, "is_ide" bool NULL);
INSERT INTO "table_application_delete_history" ("id", "name", "delete_time", "st
atus", "admin_comment", "applicant", "is_fa", "is_ide", "defect_manager_id") SEL
ECT "id", "name", "delete_time", "status", "admin_comment", "applicant", "is_fa"
, "is_ide", NULL FROM "table_application_delete_history__old";
DROP TABLE "table_application_delete_history__old";
CREATE INDEX "table_application_delete_history_defect_manager_id_d577266a" ON "t
able_application_delete_history" ("defect_manager_id");
COMMIT;
```

But DJANGO 1.9 DOESN'T!
How can i solve this problem???
I drop the new create Models ~> Can create new models but CAN'T EDIT the OLD model.

Edit 1:
I can fix it by: DELETE all the new COLUMN and migrate again.
But it can't help feel good...

Comment: Check this out `python manage.py migrate --fake`

Comment: thanks, i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this directly :

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

If above solution doesn't work follow this step by step:-

```
1.Empty the django_migrations table: delete from django_migrations;
2.For every app, delete its migrations folder: rm -rf <app>/migrations/
3.Reset the migrations for the "built-in" apps: python manage.py migrate --fake
4.For each app run: python manage.py makemigrations <app>. Take care of dependencies (models with ForeignKey's should run after their parent model).
5.Finally: python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Comment: i think i work and will let you know when i am done with it.